# android: Adding Firebase with Google Analytics Notification issue

Tags: android, google-analytics, firebase, google-cloud-messaging

I am adding Firebase to my existing Android Project which already had Google Analytics added to it. I added the project as Add Existing Google Project to Firebase.

The Events are reporting fine on Firebase but I am not able to receive gcm messages after making changes to the

> google-services.json

Also I am using Localytics to send gcm messages to the app. The configuration over there is fine. Localytics handles the fetching of GCM token in the app.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I think you should migrate from GCM to FCM as integrating `google-services.json` from Firebase would result in disruption to other Google services. Implement Firebase Cloud Messaging.

Comment: Never mind I was using the different API key. My bad

Comment: I want to use GCM and FCM simultaneously, how i can do that

Comment: @gbansal I haven't tried that. This should be new question i suppose.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Never mind. I was using the wrong API key in the google-services.json